# Getting an error with react-router-dom, that I can't solve

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, routes, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I have the following code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css'
import './styles/styles.scss'

const ExpenseDashboardPage = () => (
    <div>
        This is from my dashboard component
    </div>
)

const AddExpensePage = () => (
    <div>
        This is from my add expense component
    </div>
)

const EditExpensePage = () => (
    <div>
        This is for editing expenses component
    </div>
)

const HelpPage = () => (
    <div>
        This is help component
    </div>
)

const NotFoundPage = () => (
    <div>
        404! <Link to='/'>Go Home</Link>
    </div>
)

const Header = () => (
    <header>
        <h1>Expensify</h1>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to='/create'>Add Expense</Link>
        <Link to='/edit'>Edit Expense</Link>
        <Link to='/help'>Help</Link>
    </header>
)

const routes = (
    <div>
        <Header />
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={ExpenseDashboardPage} />
                <Route path='/create' component={AddExpensePage} />
                <Route path='/edit' component={EditExpensePage} />
                <Route path='/help' component={HelpPage} />
                <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </div>
)


ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'))
```

I am following a tutorial, however their header component works as is above; however, I am getting an error in the console with nothing rendering on the page.

`VM84 bundle.js:40892 Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`

I believe I have to do something with `withRouter`, but am not sure how to proceed.

I have a link to the github repo where the code is as well, as I am using webpack and babel to bundle my project. https://github.com/altafmquadri/expensify-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that `Links` can't be rendered outside a `Router`. All the links are rendered within the header component. Move the `Header` into the `Router`.

```
const routes = (
  <div>
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={ExpenseDashboardPage} />
        <Route path='/create' component={AddExpensePage} />
        <Route path='/edit' component={EditExpensePage} />
        <Route path='/help' component={HelpPage} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Header component needs to be inside the `Router` in order to be able to access link inside Header component.

```js
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={ExpenseDashboardPage} />
        <Route path="/create" component={AddExpensePage} />
        <Route path="/edit" component={EditExpensePage} />
        <Route path="/help" component={HelpPage} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```